# UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'gs' not implemented (file: 'gs://modelzoo/vision/other_models/InceptionV1.pb')

Tags: computer-vision, google-cloud-storage, lucid

I am implementing Lucid library following the feature visualization(https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/) which is giving this error in render.render_vis() function.

I tried using different version of tensorflow and configuring the Google Cloud Storage (GCS).
Current tensorflow version-1.15.0
numpy version-1.19.5